# MySite Add colleagues gives 404 in SP2010

Tags: 2010, my-site, mysites

We haven't really used the MySites before but only just started

However, when we click Add colleagues or Edit colleagues we get a 404 error

Saw in fiddler that it tries to request

```
/QuickLinksDialogForm.aspx?Mode=Person&IsDlg=1
```

When it really should be

```
/_layouts/QuickLinksDialogForm.aspx?Mode=Person&IsDlg=1
```

Why would SharePoint omit the layouts part and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with my site . you need to create my site host collection in central admin.

Please follow the steps to do same

http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2010/08/in-sharepoint-2010-mysite-is-not.html

After this you need to Go to Central Admin >> Manage Service Application > Select User Profile Service Application ,and click Manage on the ribbon ---> then Under My Site Settings, Click Configure Trusted Host Locations and add My Site Host collection URL, do not enter any Audience if your limiting users

Link:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/caa1dc53-a939-4030-bc2c-99be71e9abce/404-not-found-error-on-opening-my-profile-page-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Related topic:
[Sharepoint My Profile 404 NOT FOUND](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59434/sharepoint-my-profile-404-not-found)

the following script update the user profile property which hopefully resolve your issue:

```
$mySiteUrl = "http://your_site_name/"
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
foreach ($userProfile in $profiles) {
#Get user profile and change the value 
          $userProfile["PersonalSpace"].Value = ""
          $userProfile.Commit()
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, my profile works, I can click the link for colleage suggestions (which goes to /_layouts/QuickLinksDialogForm.aspx?Mode=Suggestion&IsDlg=1) but when I click Add or Edit /_layouts/ is not added before the page name